# Change chainID in frontier after chain is live

Tags: frontier, evm

We have tested in local chain with a runtime upgrade to change the chainID of the EVM (with frontier). All seems ok, chain continue to run correctly with the new chainID. Except the fact that we will need to change the config of metamask, and some others clients does it break something in the chain or it is safe to proceed with a live chain, in other words is there something we mised before proceeding ?